# Can I use approve/transferfrom function for ETH coin?

Tags: erc-20

Can I use approve/transferfrom function for ETH coin?
Please let me know how to apply approve/transferfrom to ETH as erc20 tokens.

Thank you!

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "use", what you mean by "apply", and what you mean by "ETH coin". In addition to that, please show your code and explain where you are stuck. Your question is otherwise extremely unclear and extremely unfocused!

Answer (score 1):

Not as a normal feature.

You could make a contract for it. Users would have to be convinced to keep some of their money on deposit and you would implement the ERC20 interface.

Alternatively, you could make a reserve-backed token and sale/buy-back contract offering a pegged 1:1 rate of exchange.

Possibly neither of those solutions has any practical value. You didn't say why you want to. It might be worth noting that approve and transferFrom was to address a limitation of tokens that native Eth doesn't suffer from.

Hope it helps.